# Generating quizz content from database dynamically from a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My client is a college professor who wants to add online quizzes for his students on his Wordpress-powered website, among other things. So I'm building a custom plugin that allows him or any administrator to make these quizzes from the admin pages. All this info is saved in the mysql database in their own tables, no problem here. It's when showing the quizzes to the students/regular users of the blog that I got lost.

What I wanted was a way to generate these quizzes. At first I figured a `$_GET` parameter with the quiz's ID the student wants to do would do the trick, but then, where would that even go? Should I use a separate php file in the main directory of wordpress (and would that even work)?

Should I create a regular old post and slap the code with shortcodes? Should I work with custom post types? (But remember the quizzes are already created in the database and I feel making one post, custom or regular, for each quiz seems excessive and complicated. Can you even make a wordpress page dynamic and pass it a parameter?)

Or is there a way to use hooks to rewrite the main page to show my code instead of the loop (or any other place at all)? Or am I too far off and is there another method altogether?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the knowledge to do this. And also, what do you want to do ? Select something from the database and display it ?

Comment: I can't argue with the first argument, since I'm just learning how the API works. It's just that the things I've been reading about don't seem particularly helpful for what I need to get done. Or not with a lot of tweaking at least. It's not just select and display, which I do know how to do. The students should then be able to solve the quiz and the plugin should then calculate the note/mark. But first I must get this part done and that's where I'm asking for help. I need to figure out where and how I can show these quizzes.

Comment: You need to select something from your database and display it, right ?

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter too soon. But like I was saying above, it's not all I must do and that's not where I'm stuck, but I can't do the rest of the plugin and the quiz post-processing until I know where to... attach my coding, I suppose? Posts, custom posts, hooks, a normal php file. I'm just not sure and I really need to learn what I'm supposed to learn for the task. Sigh, I apologize for sounding so vague but I'm quite lost.

Comment: Hi, Chris, welcome. Here we deal with code, your Question should focus on specific blocks that you're developing and not working. This guides are really helpful to learn how to Q&A: [ask] and [About]. I think you'll do this faster using Gravity Forms or similar. Check [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58374/12615) for Google Docs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as simply as using a custom template. For example, make a page called "Quiz" and a custom template called quiz.php. In that template you could simply look for the quiz id in the query string and then display it:

```
if($_GET['quiz_id']){
/** code to retrieve and output the quiz */
}
else{
/** code for them to select a quiz */
}
```

That's the bare bones approach. To do it in a slicker way you might use something like the rewrite endpoint API (http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

An example of that would be:

```
/** add a custom function to the init hook */
add_action('init', 'my_custom_endpoint');


/** custom endpoint for handling forms */
function my_custom_endpoint(){
  add_rewrite_endpoint('forms', EP_ALL);
  /** when pages are loaded, check to see if it's a form page and do something */
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'process_form' );
}
```

The EP_ALL is the endpoint mask -- it tells WordPress where to apply the new endpoint. You could have it apply only to pages, only to posts, etc. In this case you're adding your endpoint everywhere.

Then you have a function that actually processes the endpoint:

```
function process_form(){
  global $wp_query;
  /** check for your endpoint. A URL like site.com/forms/12 would set forms = 12 */
  if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['forms'])){
    /** the query var forms has a value, do something to show the form */
    echo get_form($wp_query->query_vars['forms']);

  }

}
```

Comment: if he doesn't know PHP, I don't really see him understanding a function... but hey, why not..

Comment: @wunderdojo Thank you so much! That's what I needed. I've managed to solve the requirement with an endpoint and it works well.

Comment: @taotrooper -- awesome, glad to hear it worked for you!